# Internal and External dns name in EC2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

My Application(openmrs) is running on ubuntu, apache, mysql.  It is configured with Public dns name: ec2-174-129-227-190.compute-1.amazonaws.com in apache. The problem is within system ID of application. It shows Internal dns name: ip-10-250-78-208.ec2.internal.  How do i change it so  it does route to internal dns name.

Comment: On AWS servers, that should happen automatically. Have you opened port 8080 to the server?

Comment: Why is the internal hostname of the server a problem? If the application needs to talk to itself, why not just use localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: Downvoted - port 8080 has no relevance to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon-provided DNS resolver that does recursive lookups on behalf of your instances has some built-in magic that translates your external hostname to your internal IP address when an internal host looks up that name.

Note the difference in these examples.

Pinging a machine's external name from outside of my EC2 network returns the external address, just as you would expect:

```
user@dev:~$ ping ec2-54-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com
PING ec2-54-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ec2-54-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.x.x.x): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=25.2 ms
```

But pinging a machine's external DNS name from a machine inside my inside EC2 network returns a pleasant surprise: the address that we actually get back is the internal address.  Note that even though I've sanitized it, I was pinging *exactly* the same hostname in these two examples.

```
user@i-0dxxxxxx:~$ ping ec2-54-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com
PING ec2-54-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com (10.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ip-10-x-x-x.ec2.internal (10.x.x.x): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=1.29 ms
```

Requests directed at your host using the external host name should work when originated both inside and outside of EC2 if your security group configuration is correct.